# Deploying an ASP.NET application database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two SQL Servers, one belongs to the web host and one is mine.

I created a database with Visual Studio with login details etc. I need to transfer it to the web host's database server. I want to know how to do that.

I created a script using `Tasks --> Generate Script` and tried executing that on the server but it references the database in the actual folder my asp.net application is in, `Users/Sora4222/documents/....aspnet.mdf`.

How do I change that so it referencing nothing that it puts it in whatever root folder is there, the thing is the database I attached was a copy of it that I put in `c:/program files/` yet the generated script is still referencing the `users/sora4222/documents/...aspnet.mdf`.

I should mention i have almost no experience with databases.

Comment: You will have to show the script. We can't see it from over here.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate script it USE the default database, suppose you are generating script for mydb then when you create script it by default genrate 
USE mydb; 
change it to your new db like
USE mynewdb;

Comment: USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [C:\USERS\SORA4222\DOCUMENTS\GPC\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF]    Script Date: 8/01/2013 3:57:45 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [C:\USERS\SORA4222\DOCUMENTS\GPC\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF]

This is some of the script generated. Im not sure if this is enough, but im not really sure what you mean by default database, just tell me what to do.